# Is the function differentiable

Tags: analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that for $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$

$$ \lim_{\mathbb{Q} \ni h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}$$

exists. Is this function differentiable at $x_0$?

Comment: Being $\mathbb{Q}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$, I would say that sattisfies the $\delta\epsilon$ definition for the derivative, and so it's differentiable.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis The $\delta\epsilon$ definition requires the limit to exist for *all* sequences $h\to0$, not just rational ones. That's exactly the problem here.

Comment: I have two thoughts about the problem: 1. use that $f$ is continuous and show that the derivative exists. 2. for a counterexample let $f$ be the integral function of some Dirichlet-type function

Comment: now continuous in $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Dear Marcinek665, if you’re truly satisfied with a particular response to your question, please accept it by clicking on the check mark beside it. This awards the owner of the response with points for the hard work that he/she has done.

Answer (score 5):

Let 
$$ L=\lim_{\mathbb Q\ni h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$
Let $(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence with $h_n\to 0$. 
We need to show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x_0+h_n)-f(x_0)}{h_n}=L.$$
Consider $$\begin{align}g\colon\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to&\mathbb R\\ h\quad\mapsto &\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}.\end{align}$$
Then $g$ is continuous and hence $|g(h_n')-g(h_n)|<\frac1n$ holds for all $h_n'\ne 0$ sufficiently close to $h_n$. Since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb R$, we thus can find $h_n'$ such that $h_n'\in\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ and $|h_n'-h_n|<\frac1n$ and $|g(h_n')-g(h_n)|<\frac1n$. Then $\mathbb Q\ni h_n'\to 0$, hence $g(h_n')\to L$ and $g(h_n)\to L$ as was to be shown.

Comment: Nicely done, +1.

Comment: that suprised me

Comment: The $h\quad\mapsto$ is more readable as simply $g(h)=$ for me.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that the limit $ \displaystyle L := \lim_{\substack{h \to 0; \\ h \in \mathbb{Q}}} \frac{f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0})}{h} $ exists.

> **Claim:** $ f $ is differentiable at $ x_{0} $.

*Proof*: Let $ (h_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ be a sequence in $ \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \} $ that converges to $ 0 $. It suffices to prove that the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_{0} + h_{n}) - f(x_{0})}{h_{n}}
$$
exists.

---

For each $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, use the continuity of $ f $ and the denseness of $ \mathbb{Q} $ to choose a $ q_{n} \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{ 0 \} $ arbitrarily close to $ h_{n} $ so that

- $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \quad |f(x_{0} + h_{n}) - f(x_{0} + q_{n})| < \left| \dfrac{h_{n}}{n} \right| $ and
- $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{q_{n}}{h_{n}} = 1 $, which automatically yields $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} q_{n} = 0 $.

---

Next, observe that
\begin{align}
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
   \frac{f(x_{0} + h_{n}) - f(x_{0})}{h_{n}}
&= \frac{f(x_{0} + h_{n}) - f(x_{0} + q_{n})}{h_{n}} +
   \frac{f(x_{0} + q_{n}) - f(x_{0})}{h_{n}} \\
&= \frac{f(x_{0} + h_{n}) - f(x_{0} + q_{n})}{h_{n}} +
   \frac{f(x_{0} + q_{n}) - f(x_{0})}{q_{n}} \cdot \frac{q_{n}}{h_{n}}.
\end{align}

---

As
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
  \left| \frac{f(x_{0} + h_{n}) - f(x_{0} + q_{n})}{h_{n}} \right|
< \left| \frac{1}{h_{n}} \cdot \frac{h_{n}}{n} \right|
= \frac{1}{n} \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0,
$$
the Squeeze Theorem yields
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_{0} + h_{n}) - f(x_{0} + q_{n})}{h_{n}} = 0.
$$

---

Therefore,
\begin{align}
   f'(x_{0})
= &\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_{0} + h_{n}) - f(x_{0})}{h_{n}} \\
= &\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ \frac{f(x_{0} + h_{n}) - f(x_{0} + q_{n})}{h_{n}} +
   \frac{f(x_{0} + q_{n}) - f(x_{0})}{q_{n}} \cdot \frac{q_{n}}{h_{n}} \right] \\
= &\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_{0} + h_{n}) - f(x_{0} + q_{n})}{h_{n}} +
   \left[ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_{0} + q_{n}) - f(x_{0})}{q_{n}} \right]
   \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{q_{n}}{h_{n}} \right) \\
= &0 + \left[ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_{0} + q_{n}) - f(x_{0})}{q_{n}} \right]
  \cdot 1 \quad (\text{By the previous paragraphs.}) \\
= &\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_{0} + q_{n}) - f(x_{0})}{q_{n}} \\
= &L. \quad (\text{By the initial hypothesis.}) \quad \spadesuit
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

This is Hagen von Eitzen's proof, but without sequences.

We may assume $x_0=f(x_0)=0$. The function $g(h):={f(h)\over h}$ $\ (h\ne0)$ is continuous, and after subtracting a linear function from $f$ our basic assumption is   $$\lim_{\Bbb Q\ni h'\to 0}g(h')=0\ .$$

Given an $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that
$$\left|g(h')\right|<\epsilon\qquad\bigl(|h'|<\delta,\ h'\in\Bbb Q)\ .$$
Assume now that $0<|h|<\delta$. Since $g$ is continuous at $h$ there is a $h'\in\Bbb Q$ with $0<|h'|<\delta$ and $|g(h')-g(h)|<\epsilon$. It follows that $|g(h)|<2\epsilon$. This proves $\lim_{h\to0} g(h)=0$, since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary.